# Does fragments currently work in sdk v0.2.6?

Tags: randori

I've tried putting my fragments in {root}/fragments/myFragment.html and also {root}/src/fragments/myFragment.html and neither seemed to work.

Also from my behaviors.css

```
.tableFragment{
    -randori-fragment: "fragments/tableFragment.html";
}
```

and I can't seem to get things going. Is there a missing step? Finally my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="tab-content boxoffice">
    <h1>Box Office</h1>
    <div class="tableFragment"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments do work.

They should be in the main project directory, not the src, just to be clear on why:

The *only* thing that goes in src is source code that is being cross compiled. HTML shouldn't be in the src folder, we don't cross compile it.

One thing I did notice... *IF* you have an older SDK, there was a bug fixed in v0.2.4 IU believe where the space between .tableFragment and { mattered. You can try adding a space there else as a next step to debug, take a look at the network tab in chrome or your browser of choice and watch what is loading. Does it try to load the HTML at all?